# How to make a column as FK from two tables in two different and unrelated services?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys

Assume that there are 2 unconnected and different services: `Service-A` & `Service-B`.

The table that I have in `Service-A`:

```
class ServiceATable(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    received_encrypted = Column(Boolean)
    encryption_author = Column(String(150))
    decryption_state = Column(Boolean)
```

The table in `Service-B`:

```
class ServiceBTable(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    id_from_service_a = Column(Integer) 
    filename = Column(String(200))
    forwarding_to = Column(String(150))
```

What I am trying to do is to use the `id` column in the `Service-A` table and make it a Foreign Key in the `Service-B` table in the column `id_from_service_a`, so that the `Service-B` table looks something like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey

class ServiceBTable(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    id_from_service_a = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('id-from-service-a'))
    filename = Column(String(200))
    forwarding_to = Column(String(150))
```

Since both the tables are in 2 different services, I don't think I can use the [Basic Relationship Patterns](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html) as it assumes that both the tables are created in the same service.

Is there a way I can achieve the following?